# Permutations and then sorting in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, loops, recursion

I have a sorting problem.

Let's say I have 4 strings stored in an array, out of these I want to generate all combinations in pairs. And from these pairs sort them so that no 2 array positions get after each other in the greatest extend possible

Example:

```
String[] array = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};

// want to generate

one - two
one - three
one - four
two - three
two - four
three - four

// then sort

one - two
three - four
one - four
two - three      //two "three" after each other
one - three
two - four
```

(the one that gets 2 after each other in this case `"three"` has too be random when sorted)

I have no idea how to do this in Java. Tried nested for loops, some has told me recursive loops. And i don't want:

"*Just copy paste this code and everything will work*" i really really want to understand how to write something like this.

How should i approach this problem?

Comment: trust me, you want it or you dont want it , you wont get ___Just copy paste this code and everything will work___  on [SO] , atleast from  members who understand the concept of the site

Comment: i added that not as a rude gesture, but i have posted the same question to another forum and not a single person went through the process of how it works. I didn't mean to offend anyone. im glad for all the help i get.

Comment: Bro, mine is not a rude gesture as well. Just for gags. Some fun in between serious posts is alright :) , I apologize if you felt offended. chill and welcome to [SO]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's your not `Just copy paste this code and everything will work`: -

> Step 1: - Initialize an temp variable to **`0`**.
>
> Step 2: - Iterate over your array from **`0` to `arr.length - temp`**
>
> Step 3: - Print **`arr[i][temp] - arr[i][i + temp]`**
>
> Step 4: - Increment `temp` by `1`
>
> Step 5: - Repeat `step 2` if **`temp < arr.length - 1`**, as **`(i
>   + temp)`** cannot be more than **`arr.length`**.

So, for the given array it will print: -

```
String arr[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
```

**First iteration (Index pair with difference 1) : -**

```
1. arr[0][0] - arr[0][1], then ("one" - "two")
2. arr[0][1] - arr[0][2],      ("two" - "three")
.. so on,
```

and then move to next iteration. Increment temp by `1`: -

**Second Iteration (Index pair with difference 2) : -**

```
1. arr[0][0] - arr[0][2], then  ("one" - "three")
2. arr[0][1] - arr[0][3]        ("two" - "four")
```

.. so on.

**Last Iteration (Index pair with difference `arr.length - 1`) : -**

```
1. max = arr.length - 1;
2. arr[0][0] - arr[0][max]      ("one" - "four")
```

So, you can see that, there is nothing as such `sorting` involved here. If you try to do this with sorting, it will be hell lot of complex.

Answer (score 1):

First come up with an algorithm. it doesn't have to have a particular language set up for it. It's just how you yourself would solve the problem.

Then translate that to the computer.

here's some psudocode to get you started.

```
public pair[] getPairs(string[] arr)
{

    pair[] retval;
    foreach(string s in arr)
    {
        string first = arr.first
        foreach(string s2 in arr.subArray(allbutfirst))
        {
             retval.Add(newPair(s, s2)
        }
    }
}
```